# Numerical averaging of a highly oscillatory data set.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, average

I have an oscillatory data set.

---

[image]

---

I want to find the average value of the set some time after the initial disturbance. I've obtained the data via RK4. In the past, for more reasonable functions, I've just used a trapezoid rule integration and divided by the range of integration. But now I'm wondering if that will work on such a weird set with sharp peaks. And would it be numerically negligent of me to simply take the mean of the y-values as the average function value, why? Any other suggestions?

Looks pretty linear, should I fit a line (or parabola) through it via least squares then integrate that?

Side question: I believe, in order to preserve the accuracy of RK4, I should be using some averaging method that preserves that 4th order accuracy, right?

Comment: It all depends on what your goal is. If you want to not worry about outliers, try finding the median instead of the mean. Or use a median filter. Then maybe fit a straight line to the filtered data.

Comment: My goal is to most accurately (with some attention to computational efficiency) determine the the "true average" function value of a continuous function that lies on this data. I'm assuming there is a continuous function that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: I think I would apply a median filter and fit a straight line to that and extrapolate from the straight line. Make the window wide enough to get several oscillations.

Comment: I would be very worried that I had made a mistake. Anything you can tell us about which differential equation you are solving and which stepsizes you used would be valuable. It may very well be that the use of a high order Runge Kutta method is not a good idea